# Count columns that are repetitions per line

Tags: awk

I have a tab delim file

```
NC_044998.1     4015    0       TT      2       GG      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      
NC_044998.1     4015    0       AT      0       TT      0       TA      2       GG      0       TT      
NC_044998.1     4016    0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      
NC_044998.1     4016    0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      
NC_044998.1     4017    2       CC      2       CT      2       CC      2       CC      2       CC
```

I wanna add a column to the end with the counts of columns which are repetitions of two letters, as in `TT` (but any letter is possible).

So that the output is

```
NC_044998.1     4015    0       TT      2       GG      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT  5  
NC_044998.1     4015    0       AT      0       TT      0       TA      2       GG      0       TT  3    
NC_044998.1     4016    0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT  5    
NC_044998.1     4016    0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT  5    
NC_044998.1     4017    2       CC      2       CT      2       CC      2       CC      2       CC  4
```

I'm currently trying to split every other column and then comparing them using

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS = OFS = "\t"} {for (i=4; i<=12; i+=2) {sub(/./,"&\t",$i)1;} print $0};' file | awk 'BEGIN {FS = OFS = "\t"} {count = 0} {for (i=4; i<=17; i+=3) {if ($i==$i-1) count+=1} END {print 0,$count}}'
```

It's splitting correctly, but it's not counting the occurrences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this awk:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN {
   FS=OFS="\t"
}
{
   c = 0
   for (i=4; length($i)==2 && i<=12; i+=2)
     substr($i,1,1) == substr($i,2,1) && c++
   print $0, c
}' file
```

```
NC_044998.1 4015    0   TT  2   GG  0   TT  0   TT  0   TT  5
NC_044998.1 4015    0   AT  0   TT  0   TA  2   GG  0   TT  3
NC_044998.1 4016    0   TT  0   TT  0   TT  0   TT  0   TT  5
NC_044998.1 4016    0   TT  0   TT  0   TT  0   TT  0   TT  5
NC_044998.1 4017    2   CC  2   CT  2   CC  2   CC  2   CC  4
```

Comment: Thanks also for this one!

Answer (score 1):

If Perl is an option, you can try this.

```
$ perl -lne '$c=0;  while(/\b(.)\1\b/g) { $c++ }  print "$_ $c"; ' madza.txt
NC_044998.1     4015    0       TT      2       GG      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT       5
NC_044998.1     4015    0       AT      0       TT      0       TA      2       GG      0       TT       3
NC_044998.1     4016    0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT       5
NC_044998.1     4016    0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT      0       TT       5
NC_044998.1     4017    2       CC      2       CT      2       CC      2       CC      2       CC       4
$
```